# Excel VBA PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set copySheet = Worksheets("Metrics")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Metrics")

copySheet.Range("A1:J5").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I have written this chunk of VBA code and it does mostly what I want it to do, but what I cannot figure out is how to apply a second pastespecial to get the formats from the Copied section to the newly pasted section.  I tried adding a second .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats under the first pastespecial line, but the macro fails at that point.

Any ideas about how to get the format to the newly pasted section?

Comment: Add it behind `xlPasteValues`. Might need a comma.

Comment: That was my first thought, tried it and it gives me a 1004 error on that line with comma, and a compile error without.

Comment: Immediately after the `PasteSpecial` line of code, put in a second `PasteSpecial` line of code for the xlPasteFormats

Comment: Wait, you can't paste values AND formats??? I mean the point of values is you don't want formats XD

Comment: @findwindow That may be true in some cases, but it is very commonly used to bring in data without the formulas.  In that case you may still want the formats.

Comment: Ah ok. You can see I never copy paste formats XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a pretty answer, but

```
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-4, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

That does end up working.  I put that right below the first pasteSheet line.

Now I have to insert the month of the year in the first cell after pasting... that will be fun.